# Getting of the variable in the function

Tags: c#

Sorry for my english :(

I have used this code:

```
for (int i = val3; i < to_val3; i++)
{
    TextBox tbx4 = (TextBox)(from t4 in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>() where t4.Name == i.ToString() select t4).First();
    str4 = tbx4.Text;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str4.Split(' ')[4]))
    {
        get_excel(str4);
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error!, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
}
```

and sent string `"str4"` to function `get_excel`:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Шаблон.xls");
ObjWorkSheet = ObjWorkBook.Sheets[2];
ObjWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = str;
ObjWorkSheet.Cells[5, 5] = str;
ObjWorkSheet.Cells[6, 6] = str;
ObjWorkSheet.Cells[7, 7] = str;
ObjExcel.Visible = false;
ObjExcel.UserControl = true;
ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
ObjWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\Шаблон_Изменен.xls");
ObjExcel.Quit();
```

My problem: I want to get only the first value of the variable from cycle (for)

Comment: What would an example value of `str4` be?

Comment: for example: I'm super programmer[1]
2) I'm super programmer[2]
=>

Comment: And from that sentence, what value would you like?

Comment: all offer
help, please :)

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood :) From `I'm super programmer[1] 2) I'm super programmer[2] =>`, what value are you trying to get?

Comment: If you want only the first value of the variable, why don't you set a `break;` after the `get_excel(str4);` call?

Comment: solved. But string[] arr = str.Split(' ');
How to add string[] arr = str.Split(' '[1]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to use `break` statement [MSDN break documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/adbctzc4.aspx)

So, somewhere in the for loop you need to set break